# Polars for Python: How to get rid of "Ensure you pass a path to the file instead of a python file object" warning when reading to a dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

#### The statement

- I'm reading data sets using `Polars.read_csv()` method via a Python file handler:

```
 with gzip.open(os.path.join(getParameters()['rdir'], dataset)) as compressed_file:
    df = pl.read_csv(compressed_file, sep = '\t', ignore_errors=True)
```

- A performance warning keeps popping up:

```
Polars found a filename. Ensure you pass a path to the file instead of a python file object when possible for best performance.
```

#### Possible solutions

- I already tried Python warning suppression, but it seems Polars literally just prints out this statement without any default warning associated.
- Another possibility would be to read using non-handler methods?

Any ideas on how to get rid of this annoying message will be highly appreciated.

Comment: did you try passing `os.path.join(getParameters()['rdir'], dataset)` directly to `read_csv`?

Comment: Warnings and Errors are different classes in Python and are suppressed differently. How did you "[try] Python warning suppression"?

Comment: @PaulH Yeah I already tried. The problem is that I need to use the `gzip.open()` method. This I believe is what is raising the warning, since it's not a path.

For your second question, I used the `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')` method.

Comment: Did you try doing what the warning said?

Comment: When you passed the file name directly, what happened?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I cannot with the current approach since I need to use the `gzip.open()` method, otherwise I would have to decompress.

Comment: @PaulH It returns the same warning since I'm also passing the unzipping method as argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar issue with opening from a `ZipFile` object. The solution was to add a `.read()` method to the filename. Maybe the same would work in your case?

```py
 with gzip.open(os.path.join(getParameters()['rdir'], dataset)) as compressed_file:
    df = pl.read_csv(compressed_file.read(), sep = '\t', ignore_errors=True)
```

Comment: Fantastic @RustyPython, this worked like a charm. I am setting your answer as the solution.

Comment: Note for future use: this asks python to read the whole file into memory before passing it over to polars. I think this could run out of memory in situations where passing the IO object would not.

Comment: This requires you to load the entire file buffer into memory. Not only does this negate the advantage of lazy-frames, but it ends up requiring even more memory than the dataframe once loaded as the buffer ALSO exists in memory during load.